# Getting a KEGG ontology count table from EC/MetaCyc count table

Tags: database, annotations

I have some microbiome data that was generated through shotgun metagenomics by an external provider. They provided me with count tables of species, MetaCyc pathways, enzymes (EC) and transporters (TCDB), but I do not have a count table with KEGG ontology features (e.g. IDs: K01234). I want to perform an analysis which requires me to have the data in this format, however it has proven quite difficult to obtain it.
I managed to extract a list of the EC IDs mapped to the KEGG ontology
(KO) IDs from https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/docs/weblinks.html#entry , but often there would be multiple KO IDs corresponding to 1 EC name. This is why I have struggled to actually convert them.
For example, for EC **2.1.1.175**, I get **K00746, K00747, K13499** and **K13500**.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can actually convert my count table?